# Clarification need on calling a function in the kernel

Tags: c, linux, function, include, kernel

I am having an issue calling a function (ext3_get_inode_loc) into exec.c that exists in several other files.

I should mention that I am fairly new to this and entirely self-taught so I'm sure I have major knowledge gaps.  What I would really appreciate are pointers or advice on what I'm missing, and/or where to look for answers.

Below is the result of a recursive grep from the Linux-3.10.0.123.20.1.el7 directory  -

```
"grep ext3_get_inode_loc -R *"

fs/ext3/inode.c: 
fs/ext3/inode.c:static int __ext3_get_inode_loc(struct inode *inode,  
fs/ext3/inode.c:ext3_error (inode->i_sb, ext3_get_inode_loc",  
fs/ext3/inode.c:ext3_error(inode->i_sb, ext3_get_inode_loc",  
fs/ext3/inode.c:int ext3_get_inode_loc(struct inode *inode, struct ext3_iloc *iloc)  
fs/ext3/inode.c:return __ext3_get_inode_loc(inode, iloc,  
fs/ext3/inode.c:ret = __ext3_get_inode_loc(inode, &iloc, 0);  
fs/ext3/inode.c:err = ext3_get_inode_loc(inode, iloc);  
fs/ext3/inode.c:err = ext3_get_inode_loc(inode, &iloc);  
fs/ext3/ext3.h:extern int ext3_get_inode_loc(struct inode *, struct ext3_iloc *);  
fs/ext3/xattr.c:error = ext3_get_inode_loc(inode, &iloc);  
fs/ext3/xattr.c:error = ext3_get_inode_loc(inode, &iloc);  
fs/ext3/xattr.c:error = ext3_get_inode_loc(inode, &is.iloc);
```

which shows it exists in these 3 files only -

```
ext3.h  
inode.c  
xattr.c
```

ext3.h includes the function prototype

```
extern int ext3_get_inode_loc(struct inode *, struct ext3_iloc *);
```

inode.c and xattr.c both include ext3.h providing the prototype to both files

```
#include "ext3.h"
```

inode.c includes the function definition  -

```
static int __ext3_get_inode_loc(struct inode *inode, struct ext3_iloc *iloc, int in_mem)
{
    ext3_fsblk_t block;
    struct buffer_head *bh;

    block = ext3_get_inode_block(inode->i_sb, inode->i_ino, iloc);
    if (!block)
            return -EIO;

    bh = sb_getblk(inode->i_sb, block);
.
.
... and so forth
}
```

And the function call itself -

```
err = ext3_get_inode_loc(inode, iloc);
```

xattr.c includes only the call, not the definition -

```
error = ext3_get_inode_loc(inode, &iloc);
```

My question is, if I add the exact same line of code -

```
error = ext3_get_inode_loc(inode, &iloc);
```

to open_exec() within exec.c in the same manner of xattr.c (without the function definition) I get the following error when compiling with "make" -

```
fs/built-in.o: In function `open_exec':
~/linux-3.10.0-123.20.1.el7/fs/exec.c:828: undefined reference to `ext3_get_inode_loc'
```

Why is the function available to xattr.c and not exec.c?  I've googled quite a bit on this and have read that this might be due to a linking issue (or lack thereof) between exec.c and xattr.c

Thanks ahead of time - Rog

Comment: Did you `#include ext3.h`? How are you compiling it?

Comment: Yes, I included ext3/ext.h and am compiling with "make" from the source directory which has produced bootable running kernels in the past, prior to this current issue.

Answer (score 0):

`ext3_get_inode_loc` is local for ext3 driver, located at fs/ext3. You cannot call it outside of driver code.